Layout doesn’t look as it should because I accidentally made changes
I recently started learning Blender, and while switching to the Shading tab, I accidentally altered the layout and scene. It no longer looks like it did when I first started a new project. How can I restore it to the default setup?


Go to File > Defaults > Load Factory settings

The interface in Blender is fairly standard so it isn't particularly unique. Each tab features specific sections with default Editors, but you're free to customize them according to your preferences.
From the documentation about Areas:

The Blender window is divided into a number of rectangles called
Areas. Areas reserve screen space for Editors, such as the 3D Viewport
or the Outliner. Each Editor offers a specific piece of functionality.

Here's how the Shading tab is structured and appears by default:

File Browser
3D Viewport
Image Editor
Shader Editor
Outliner
Properties


When you click the Editor Type button located in the upper-left corner of each yellow-boxed Editor, you'll see a list of all available Editors to choose from:

You can easily add (split) or remove (join) Editors by referring to the Split/Join Editors Documentation. While you can recreate the Shading tab to its default setup, it's not necessary—just open the Editors that best suit your workflow. There's no need to use File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings, as this will reset all configurations, not just the user interface layout.
If you want to learn more about Editors and their subdivisions, you can read about Regions.
